# Getting a specific value within the hierarchy of an object

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to get the root category name out of an AWS response. The ECS PHP class returns it as a class. If this was XML, I could just do an xpath search. I don't know the equivalent for searching an object.

Here is the object structure starting from the BrowseNode element:

```
object(stdClass)#172 (1) {
  ["BrowseNode"]=>
  object(stdClass)#173 (3) {
    ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
    string(8) "11059391"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(22) "Makeup Brushes & Tools"
    ["Ancestors"]=>
    object(stdClass)#174 (1) {
      ["BrowseNode"]=>
      object(stdClass)#175 (3) {
        ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
        string(8) "11062741"
        ["Name"]=>
        string(19) "Tools & Accessories"
        ["Ancestors"]=>
        object(stdClass)#176 (1) {
          ["BrowseNode"]=>
          object(stdClass)#177 (4) {
            ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
            string(8) "11055981"
            ["Name"]=>
            string(8) "Products"
            ["IsCategoryRoot"]=>
            bool(true)
            ["Ancestors"]=>
            object(stdClass)#178 (1) {
              ["BrowseNode"]=>
              object(stdClass)#179 (2) {
                ["BrowseNodeId"]=>
                string(7) "3760911"
                ["Name"]=>
                string(6) "Beauty"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, if "IsCategoryRoot" is TRUE, I need to get the value in "Name" under the next "Ancestors" element. In this case "Beauty" would be the value.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily write a function to recurse into the object and look for the node:

```
function find_category_root_name (stdClass $node) {
    if(isset($node->IsCategoryRoot) && $node->IsCategoryRoot === true) {
        if(isset($node->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Name) && !empty($node->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Name)) {
            return $node->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Name;
        } else {
            // error IsCategoryRoot found but no name found for ancestor
            return false;
        }
    } else if (isset($node->Ancestors->BrowseNode) && $node->Ancestors->BrowseNode instanceof stdClass) {
        return find_category_root_name($node->Ancestors->BrowseNode);
    } else {
        // error no ancestor node found
        return false;
    }
}

find_category_root_name($outer_object->BrowseNode);
```

Comment: Looking like that will be the way to go. Was hoping there was just a simple object search method I had missed somewhere in the PHP docs...or a way to transform the AWS SOAP response into an XML searchable structure.

Comment: You can certainly use approaches like reflection or basic `property_exists()` calls, but the main issue here is that you have nested objects, so you would need to recurse.  My guess is that this object was at one point a JSON response that was run through `json_decode` (based on it being all `stdClass` objects), so one possible alternative approach would be to `json_encode` it and perform a regex search (or a series of regular string searches) to extract the value you are looking for from the string.  This seems a little hacky to me though.

Comment: I have to agree. Will just stick with the recursive search. Thanks for the suggestions! :)